# Кросс-компиляция в Pyinstaller

Tags: python-3.x, linux, windows, exe, кросс-компиляция

Мне нужно упаковать Python файл в EXE для Windows.
Я работаю на Linux. Прочитал, что старые версии Pyinstaller поддерживают кросс-компиляцию. Подскажите, пожалуйста, какие именно версии мне нужны, и где их можно найти? Спасибо.

Comment: Linux позволяет установить виндовс на этот же диск установите и делайте EXE на виндовс

Comment: Это в документации советуют

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно использовать Pyinstaller из под Wine.